# Want to check Recordset has some value or not

Tags: asp-classic, ternary-operator

Here is a record set.

```
...
 Set adoCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 Set adoConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
...
 adoCommand.CommandText = strQuery
 Set adoRecordset = adoCommand.Execute
```

And I need to check this recordset has some value or not.

```
If adoRecordset.Fields("userid").Value Then 
   'do something...
Else
   'do something...
End If
```

I just tried to check but this code makes occurs an error.
**(The Error message below is translated by Google)**

```
ADODB.Recordset Error '800a0cc1'
Item cannot be found in the collection corresponding to the requested name or ordinal
```

If possible, I want to use Ternary operator.
I don't know which part is wrong.

```
userid = adoRecordset.Fields("userid").Value ? adoRecordset.Fields("userid").Value : sw
```

Please understand that I'm a very newbie to asp, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check for the existence of any rows in the resultset *before* attempting to access them by name:

```
If adoRecordset.eof Then 
  '//no rows
else
  '//
```

There is no ternary operator in VBScript.

Answer (score 2):

Try following example:

```
if adoRecordset.EOF Then
  REM do something
else
  REM do something
end if
```

Comment: Edit: The line with .movefirst deleted, because it can run into an error.